# List.Generate() Expression error: table to text

Tags: powerquery, m

I am testing the list.generate() on an easy example, for much more complicated scenarios that I encounter at work on. The function needs to perform in each step a transformation of a table that includes filtering by using a custom function. I created two similar variations of the operation, and one yields the correct result whereas the other one fails, but I do not understand why.

This is the starting table of a simple example that I want to transform with the custom function:

[image]

I want to filter the content by each year and apply some transformation, in every step. I have created a list with unique values of years and it feeds the list.generate() function.

This is the output I need after iterative transformations:

[image]

This is the code that yields the correct result:

```
let 
Transformed = List.Generate(()=> [Year = List.Min(Years), Function = FilterAndTransform(Year,"Table1")],
                 each [Year] <= List.Max(Years), 
                 each [Year = [Year]+1, Function = FilterAndTransform([Year]+1, "Table1")],
                 each [Function]),
    #"Converted to Table" = Table.FromList(Transformed, Splitter.SplitByNothing(), null, null, ExtraValues.Error),
    #"Expanded Column1" = Table.ExpandTableColumn(#"Converted to Table", "Column1", {"Column1", "PAX", "ASK", "RPK"}, {"Column1.Column1", "Column1.PAX", "Column1.ASK", "Column1.RPK"})
in
    #"Expanded Column1"
```

This is the custom function FilterAndTransform inside:

```
(Year as number, Table as text) =>
let 
    Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name=Table]}[Content],
    Filtered = Table.SelectRows(Source, each ([Column1] = Year)),
    Pivoted = Table.Pivot(Filtered, List.Distinct(Filtered[Column2]), "Column2", "Column3", List.Sum)
in
    Pivoted
```

Now, if I change the code to this:

```
let
    Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Table1"]}[Content],
    Transformed = List.Generate(()=> [Year = List.Min(Years), Function = FilterAndTransformM(Year, Source)],
                 each [Year] <= List.Max(Years), 
                 each [Year = [Year]+1, Function = FilterAndTransform([Year]+1, Source)],
                 each [Function])
in
    Transformed
```

where the custom function FilterAndTransformM is different from the previous one as it only includes transformations step, and not the loading of table:

```
(Year as number, Table as table) =>
let 
    Filtered = Table.SelectRows(Table, each ([Column1] = Year)),
    Pivoted = Table.Pivot(Filtered, List.Distinct(Filtered[Column2]), "Column2", "Column3", List.Sum)
in
    Pivoted
```

I get the following error:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9LkPN.png)
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6GSfO.png)

Obviously the function does not quite behave as I expect. I expected it will refer in every step to the table, do transformations and list stack them as in the first case.  Can you please help me understand why does it fail, why does the operation want to convert a table to text in the first place?

Answer (score 0):

I will just mention that there is no reason to do what you are doing

The first set of transformations, for example, can be done with a single step

```
 #"Pivoted Column" = Table.Pivot(Source, List.Distinct(#"Changed Type"[Column2]), "Column2", "Column3", List.Sum)
```

[image]